# Not able to use all processors when using multiprocessing in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-multiprocessing

I am working on python and trying to learn multiprocessing. When I tried the following code, it is supposed to run parallely but it is only using one processor. I am not able to understand the cause. What could be the issue,  Why it is not engaging all the 4 cores of my pc.

**The code I tried is as follows:**

```
import multiprocessing
import time
start = time.perf_counter()

def do_something():
    print("hello")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("done")

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something())
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something())
p1.start()
p2.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()
finish = time.perf_counter()
print(f'finished in {round(finish-start,1)} sec')
```

---

**Result:**

```
hello
done
hello
done
finished in 2.1 sec
```

---

*It should execute in 1 sec (approx.)*

#

**The code I used to find the number of cores:**

#

```
import multiprocessing
print("Number of cpu : ", multiprocessing.cpu_count())
```

---

**Result:**

```
Number of cpu :  4
```

---

#

**One more code I tried is:**

#

```
from multiprocessing import Lock, Process, Queue, current_process
import time
import queue # imported for using queue.Empty exception


def do_job(tasks_to_accomplish, tasks_that_are_done):
    while True:
        try:
            '''
                try to get task from the queue. get_nowait() function will 
                raise queue.Empty exception if the queue is empty. 
                queue(False) function would do the same task also.
            '''
            task = tasks_to_accomplish.get_nowait()
        except queue.Empty:

            break
        else:
            '''
                if no exception has been raised, add the task completion 
                message to task_that_are_done queue
            '''
            print(task)
            tasks_that_are_done.put(task + ' is done by ' + current_process().name)
            time.sleep(.5)
    return True


def main():
    number_of_task = 10
    number_of_processes = 4
    tasks_to_accomplish = Queue()
    tasks_that_are_done = Queue()
    processes = []

    for i in range(number_of_task):
        tasks_to_accomplish.put("Task no " + str(i))

    # creating processes
    for w in range(number_of_processes):
        p = Process(target=do_job(tasks_to_accomplish, tasks_that_are_done))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()

    # completing process
    for p in processes:
        p.join()

    # print the output
    while not tasks_that_are_done.empty():
        print(tasks_that_are_done.get())

    return True


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

---

**Result:**

```
Task no 0
Task no 1
Task no 2
Task no 3
Task no 4
Task no 5
Task no 6
Task no 7
Task no 8
Task no 9
Task no 0 is done by MainProcess
Task no 1 is done by MainProcess
Task no 2 is done by MainProcess
Task no 3 is done by MainProcess
Task no 4 is done by MainProcess
Task no 5 is done by MainProcess
Task no 6 is done by MainProcess
Task no 7 is done by MainProcess
Task no 8 is done by MainProcess
Task no 9 is done by MainProcess
```

---

#

**After suggestions I changed few things as follows:**

```
import multiprocessing
import time
start = time.perf_counter()

def do_something():
    print("hello")
    time.sleep(1)
    print("done")

p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something)
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something)
p1.start()
p2.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()
finish = time.perf_counter()
print(f'finished in {round(finish-start,1)} sec')
```

**Result I am getting is:**

```
finished in 0.2 sec
```

Comment: how do you know which cores are been used or not?

Comment: @Netwave, Sir by using code second it is showing which processor is utilised in execution of the code.

Answer (score 7):

The target needs to be the callable.

```
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=do_something)
```

The way you had it, you were calling the method in the main process and passing the result to multiprocessing.

Comment: Hello Sir, I tried with your way but when executing the code it is not running the code inside the functoin (do_something) and completing the execution in less than 0.2 sec.

Comment: Can't repeat that. Works fine for me; prints two hellos and two dones, and finished in 1.0 sec.

Comment: then what could be the issue, I tried the same code on google cloud platform but results where same.

Comment: Add to your question the exact code you used and the result you got.

Comment: Yes Sir, I added the suggestions in my questions and you can look at the changes and tell me what could be the issue for such result. Thank you

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`partial`](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/functools.html#functools.partial) in order to bind the function to the parameters. Currently you are just calling the function:

```
from functools import partial
...
for w in range(number_of_processes):
        p = Process(target=partial(do_job, tasks_to_accomplish, tasks_that_are_done))
        processes.append(p)
        p.start()
```

As @DanielRoseman suggested it is even better to pass the arguments in the `Process` call:

```
Process(target=do_job, args=(tasks_to_accomplish, tasks_that_are_done))
```

Comment: No need for that. You can pass the arguments directly as the `args` parameter: `Process(target=do_job, args=(tasks_to_accomplish, tasks_that_are_done))`

Comment: Hello Sir, I tried both your suggestions but code execute instantly without printing anything (without running the functions)